# How to list category, sub category, menus using eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have started learning Laravel and playing with eloquent relationships. I have completed listing with Category & Sub Category wise but now I don't understand for how to display menu under Category & Sub Category.

```
My Example:
----------
Category 1
  --Menu 1
  --Menu 2
  --Sub Category 1
    --Menu 3
Category 2
  --Menu 4
Category 3
    -- Sub Category 2
       --Menu 5
```

### Route:

```
Route::get('/menus/list', 'API\UserController@getMenus');
```

### UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\RoleUser;
use App\Articles;
use App\Menus;
use App\MainCategory;
use App\SubCategory;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getMenus()
    {
        $categories = MainCategory::with('sub_category')->get();
        return $categories;
    }
}
```

### MainCategory.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MainCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'main_category';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id', 'user_id', 'name', 'content'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function parent_category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }


    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function sub_category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

### Menus.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menus extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'menus';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'category_id', 'name', 'content', 'created_at', 'status'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
}
```

After running above code I am getting this results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Category 1",
    "content": "Maiores eligendi voluptates similique ullamco eum maxime et dicta temporibus sunt vel dicta labore temporibus",
    "status": 1,
    "sub_category": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": null,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Category 2",
    "content": "Quis quidem in in ut est adipisci pariatur Et sed odit",
    "status": 1,
    "sub_category": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "name": "Sub Category",
        "content": "Impedit voluptatum saepe commodo nulla sint voluptate consequatur Nihil autem",
        "status": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": null,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Category 3",
    "content": "Beatae voluptatibus excepturi qui harum ad aliquip laudantium molestiae reprehenderit esse",
    "status": 1,
    "sub_category": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parent_id": null,
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Category 4",
    "content": "Ea tempor voluptate non ducimus et cillum nisi rem natus id voluptas laboriosam voluptatum voluptatibus tempor quo fugit",
    "status": 1,
    "sub_category": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Sub Category",
    "content": "Impedit voluptatum saepe commodo nulla sint voluptate consequatur Nihil autem",
    "status": 1,
    "sub_category": [

    ]
  }
]
```

### My Tables:

[image]

[image]

Any Idea how to implement relation for menus as I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will need to define a relationship to your `Menus` model in your `MainCategory` model:

```
class MainCategory extends Model {
    ....

    public function menus() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Menus', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    ....
}
```

Then, since you are eager loading the `sub_category`, you'll need to tell Laravel load other relations as well, since eager loading will only return that relation. See the docs for more info on eager loading (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Example:

```
$categories = MainCategory::with('parent_category.menus', 'sub_category.menus')->get();
```

**Edit**:

Since you are eager loading your menu as a relation to the `parent_category` and `sub_category` relations, you will need to call the menu directly from those relations.

Example:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    foreach ($category->parent_category as $parent) {
        foreach ($parent->menus as $menu) {
            //Do something with your menu
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to include the relation directly to the `$categories` object (e.g. to call via `$categories->menus`), you'll need to update your eager load to include the menus relation as an additional argument.

Comment: I am getting this error: ``Call to undefined relationship [menus] on model [App\MainCategory].
``

Comment: That's because the menu is being eager loaded under the `parent_category` and `sub_category` relationship. I'll update my answer to explain.